# How do I get the array values from two arrays by using keys

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

My arrays are

```
 $name=>
    Array
        (
            [0] => General
            [1] => General
            [2] => Outdoors
            [3] => Dining
            [4] => Dining
            [5] => Kitchen
            [6] => Kitchen

        )

 $key1=>
   Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 11
            [4] => 12
            [5] => 17
            [6] => 18
        )
```

Array function

```
 foreach ($key1 as $key => $value1) {
                    foreach ($name as $key => $value) {

                        echo $value "=>" $value1 ;
                        //echo "$value1";
                    }
                }
```

Here I would like to print the values by using the same keys

if  `$name` having the index as `[0]` and my `$key1` also take the `[0]` value

i.e: my result should be in the form of

```
General => 1
General => 2
Outdoors => 7
Dining => 11
Dining => 12
Kitchen => 17
Kitchen => 18
```

Comment: `foreach ($name as $key => $value) { echo $value "=>" $key1[$key];} `

Comment: each `foreach` will be multiplied to the number of results in nested setting. so, in your code you'll have `36` outputs. Just use foreach once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to iterate one array, not both of them:

```
foreach ($name as $key => $name_value) {
    echo "$name_value => " . $key1[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for loop to do this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
    echo $name[$i] . '=>' . $key[$i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you're using the same variable `$key` for both foreachs, so the last one overwrites the value.

```
foreach ($key1 as $key => $value1) {
    foreach ($name as $key => $value) {

        echo $value "=>" $value1 ;
        //echo "$value1";
    }
}
```

You could make things easier by combining those two arrays, making `$name` array be the keys and `$key1` array be the values

```
$newArray = array_combine($name, $key1);
foreach ($newArray as $name => $key) {
    echo "{$name} =>{$key}";
}
```

Comment: Here if the keys having same name then it took only the last value:i.e:General=>2 and for Dining => 12 and for Kitchen => 18..But I need all the values

Comment: Thats right, I forgot about that detail, you should than use @Mureinik 's code.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
<?php 
$a1= array('General','Outdoors','Dining ');
$a2= array('1','2','3');
$newArr=array();
foreach($a1 as $key=> $val)
{
    $newArr[$a2[$key]]= $val;
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($newArr); 
?>
```

output

```
Array
(
    [1] => General
    [2] => Outdoors
    [3] => Dining 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this wont be possible if you want the output as associative array as same key name in an associative array is not allowed. It would be always overwritten if you are dealing with the associative arrays.

Although you may have something like this:

`array_map(function($key, $val) {return array($key=>$val);}, $name, $key1)`

Output:

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [General] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [General] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [Outdoors] => 7 ) [3] => Array ( [Dining] => 11 ) [4] => Array ( [Dining] => 12 ) [5] => Array ( [Kitchen] => 17 ) [6] => Array ( [Kitchen] => 18 ) )`.

**But if you want the output in string format It is possible**.

`for ($i = 0; $i < count($key); $i++) {
    echo $name[$i] . '=>' . $key[$i].'<br>';
}`

Answer (score 1):

Just change the foreach as follows...

```
foreach ($key1 as $key => $value1) {
                   echo $name[$key] ."=>". $value1."<br>";
            }
```

replace the `<br>` with `\n` if you're running through the linux terminal. Also don't miss the '`.`' operator to concatenate the string..

Nested foreach won't do what you need... Good luck..